# Serial de instalação para APP Android

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um app em anrdoid, e gostaria de saber se tem como colocar um serial para a instalação do APP, para que possa ser usado apenas no tablet em que instalado?

Caso tenha outras formas de fazer isso no Android poderiam me informar.

Comment: Não seria melhor você publicar o app na play store, e colocar como pago ? Se não servir, você faz um banco de chaves válidas e colocar o app para validar após pré instalação.

Comment: Pensei desta forma do banco de dados e validar via web, assim teria um controle de quantos tablets estão sendo instalados o app. @vcrzy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Penso que o caminho a seguir será o [Serviço de licenciamento da app](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) oferecido pela Google Play:

> Google Play oferece um serviço de licenciamento que permite reforçar as políticas de licenciamento para aplicativos que você publica no Google Play. Com Google Play Licensing, sua aplicação pode consultar o Google Play em tempo de execução para obter o status de licenciamento para o usuário atual, em seguida, permitir ou não a continuação da utilização conforme o caso.

<sup>Tradução livre.</sup>

E mais abaixo podemos ler:

> O serviço de licenciamento é um meio seguro de controlar o acesso a seus aplicativos. Quando um aplicativo verifica o status de licenciamento, o Google Play sinais servidor a resposta status de licenciamento usando um par de chaves que está associada exclusivamente com o aplicativo. O aplicativo armazena a chave do público no seu arquivo .apk compilado e usa-lo para verificar a resposta de status de licenciamento.

<sup>Tradução livre.</sup>

Existe uma série de passos a seguir, mas podes consultar o guia passo a passo disponibilizado:

## [Adicionando Licenciamento para a App](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html)

Comment: Vou estudar isso e ver qual a melhor opção para o app que estou fazendo, e no caso ver a opção no Google Play.